# Jenkins pipeline Logging

Tags: logging, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We started to migrate our simple jobs to pipeline and i would like to make some logging from that. Mainly diagnostic logging about the durations,usage and outputs of our custom stages.

So my question is:
Is there a simple way to integrate our pipeline jobs with any log analyzer tool like logstash? With a plugin that is compatible with pipeline?

So the flow will be something like:

- Make some tricky logging in the groovy script(log info ..message..)
- After or during the build we send them to the "tool"
- We can make some query or see the result on graphs.

Other way is to send the full build log to a tool and then after some process we reach our goal.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: you can use these APIs to fetch job status, test results and many more
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25685928/3201354

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm looking for a certain tool that can integrate with jenkins. Throught some plugin maybe. Writing my own solution with restcalls looks a bit overhead now. But its still an option :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So our solution was this:

- Add Log4j for logging
  Use [Grape](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html) for dependency management
  You have to solve the serialization problem(NonCPS or other way)
- Used the log4j 2 gelf appender
  It is a predefined appender for log4j 2. More details [here](https://github.com/Graylog2/log4j2-gelf)
  You can feed your logs messages to graylog with this.
- Graylog2 to create dashboards
  There is more details [here](https://www.graylog.org/)

Other alternatives:
 - Datadog 
 - ELK stack

Comment: were you able to add log4j to your jenkins pipeline? I haven't been able to do that. I don't see my logs on jenkins console output