# How to integrate Rest API with Jenkins ? Is there any plugin available for Rest API in Jenkins?

Tags: rest, jenkins

I want to integrate our Rest API with Jenkins, is there any way to do that or any plugin available in Jenkins?

Comment: does the following thread answer your question?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661362/where-can-i-find-jenkins-restful-api-reference

Comment: What do you mean by `our Rest API` ??? Can you please make yourself a little extra clear please?

Comment: I mean the Rest API.. we are using RestAPI in our instance so I mentioned our Rest API

Comment: If you're using blue ocean, you can use https://github.com/jenkinsci/blueocean-plugin/tree/master/blueocean-rest. It is a private API however and may break over time.