# Controlling Jenkins through REST API

Tags: java, rest, jenkins

Is there any REST API available to control the operations of Jenkins jobs etc.?

I see two different API clients for Java. 
https://github.com/cdancy/jenkins-rest
https://github.com/jenkinsci/java-client-api

Which one of it is official or the latest one?

Is there any documentation of endpoints that are available in Jenkins which we can use and construct the client side piece of code?

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661362/where-can-i-find-jenkins-restful-api-reference, sb mark this post as duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jenkins api https://jenkinsapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or remot api https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

you can hit endpoints and manage jobs as explained in http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/jenkins/using-jenkins-rest-api-to-manage-your-jobs-remotely