# How to takescreen shot of webpage complete top to bottom using powershell scripting

Tags: powershell, webpage-screenshot

I am able to take screenshot using below link :
https://gist.github.com/guitarrapc/9870497
but my issue is , screenshot is getting captured what you are seeing on the screen , but i want to have the screenshot of complete webpage ,i.e part which is not covering on the display screen , is it possible ? Help is appreciated , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be a screenshot then. A screenshot itself means what is visible on screen. You need to consider zoom out on page contents through code and snap the complete screen then.

Comment: But this is making the page very smaller , cannot be able to view the page properly

Answer (score 0):

------------ check below URL:
https://github.com/dafthack/PowerWebShot

Comment: is this C# ? because am seeing it is asking for webdriver.dll file , is their a way for Java ?

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Google Chrome have the ability to do this in the dev tools - [A quick tutorial](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/151-screenshot-capture/)

For the automation, I think your only choice will be to use Puppeteer to drive Chrome.

Of course, a third party tool such as [GreenShot](https://getgreenshot.org/) or [PicPick](https://ngwin.com/picpick) can be used, but I don't know if they can be automated.

Javascript using puppeteer to take a fullpage screen shot:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png', fullPage: true});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Problem with chrome is , not able to populate few of the graphs when loaded the HTML page , i want to take screenshot of jenkins HTML build report and attach in the email

Comment: What web browser are you using, then?

Comment: IE , i have report getting generated using HTML publish plugin in jenkins , now i want to send this as body of the email ,using Email Ext Plugin , so i am planning to take the screenshot of the report using powershell and attach in the body

Comment: For that, you would most likely be better off to use the Jenkins API to grab the information and format as you wish.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the same ? how exactly i can use that and what exact API i should point to ?

Comment: as i said am using published HTML report plugin and my html report is getting generated through jenkins

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661362/where-can-i-find-jenkins-restful-api-reference) has some pointers to the API docs.